# Why isn't this Python logging.exception working?

Tags: python, django, logging

I have a piece of Python code which should write an error message and the associated stacktrace to my Django logfile if an IOError exception is raised.  What I'm finding, though, is that the error and stacktrace are written to my console but not my logfile.  I've checked my Django logging configuration and don't see the problem.  I have the LOG_LEVEL set to DEBUG and I have a "logfile" handler.   Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
# photo.py
import os
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
import shutil

pvt_photo_path = "/www/proj/pvt/photo1.jpg"
pub_photo_path = "/www/proj/pub/photo1.jpg"
try:
    shutil.move(pvt_photo_path, pub_photo_path)
except IOError as e:
    logging.exception("Couldn't move photo %s" % pvt_photo_path)


# settings.py
LOG_LEVEL = 'DEBUG'
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
        },
        'logfile': {
            'level':LOG_LEVEL,
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/log/proj/proj.log',
            'maxBytes': 50000,
            'backupCount': 2,
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
        'database_logfile': {
            'level':LOG_LEVEL,
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/log/proj/database.log',
            'maxBytes': 50000,
            'backupCount': 2,
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
        'console':{
            'level':LOG_LEVEL,
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard'
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['logfile', 'database_logfile', 'console', 'mail_admins'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'DEBUG',
        },
        'django.request': {
           'handlers': ['logfile', 'mail_admins'],
           'level': 'ERROR',
           'propagate': False,
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['database_logfile'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            # Logging messages are not passed to the handlers of ancestor loggers.
            'propagate': False,
        },
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}


root: ERROR: Couldn't move photo for user "test_user"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/www/proj/classes/photo.py", line 1167, in make_photo_public
    shutil.move(pvt_gall_photo_path, pub_gall_photo_path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 301, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/www/proj/pvt/photo1.jpg'
--------------------- >> end captured logging << ---------------------
```

Comment: Can you show the stack trace? In which module is the code which raises the exception?

Comment: I've added the stacktrace.

Comment: From what you've shown, the code which raises the exception is called at *import time* - which would likely be *before* Django gets initialised and logging gets configured. Although you say it's actually called from within a method, the fact that the error message doesn't use the configured format tells me that the exception is being hit *before* logging gets configured.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're accessing the `logging` module's `exception` method. You really want to access the `logger` instance of the `logging` module instead. So, try this:

```
try:
    shutil.move(pvt_photo_path, pub_photo_path)
except IOError as e:
    logger.exception("Couldn't move photo %s" % pvt_photo_path)
```

This sort of thing is described in the `logging` module's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception).

The way you've set up your question, however, makes it impossible for me to debug this directly. The code you posted doesn't use `LOG_LEVEL` or `LOGGING` variables that you supplied, doesn't import Django, and doesn't set up a logging handler at all.

So, I'm assuming you haven't actually done what you posted in the code, just that you left out the part where you create and use a file handler appropriately. It would help if you included a simple demo of broken code so we could reproduce your error: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Unfortunate. Could you make a test case? If I run the code you've given, I don't expect it to write the log to a file. Preferably, could you make source code that has the minimal amount of coding that reproduces your error, in a single file?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the exception is being raised in the `shutil` module, and it's not being logged to one of the `django.xxx` loggers to which you have attached the file handlers - it's being logged to the root logger because you're doing `logging.exception(...)` in `photo.py`. (see [the docs for that function](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/logging.html#logging.exception)). So the error is passed to the root logger's handlers. You can see this from the fact that the exception message starts

```
root: ERROR:
```

Moreover, the exception's apparently being hit even before the Django machinery is initialised (for example, logging is not using the format you set in the logging config, but rather the default format which is used when you call `basicConfig()` or `logging.XXX()` *without* configuring logging).

I can't tell how the code in `photo.py` is being invoked, but (unless you've left stuff out) it doesn't look like it's being called from Django after Django has been initialised and set up logging as per your configuration - it looks as if it's being called much earlier.

Comment: Vinay, this is being called from Django.  I have a Django view which imports a photo class method that contains this code.  The view calls that method.  Is there perhaps something more that I need to add to my logging settings so that any errors detected by the root logger will get written to my logfile?  Thanks.